# How to summon a minecraft mob wearing a chestplate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon an army of pigmen for a build, but they wont spawn with chestplates. Every other armor item, but not chestplates! This is the command

```
/summon zombie_pigman ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1,ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:golden_boots},{Count:1,id:golden_chestplate}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your golden chestplate is in the leggings armor slot. Here is a working command that will summon a Zombie Pigman with a Gold Chestplate:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie_pigman ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{id:"minecraft:golden_chestplate",Count:1},{}]}
```

It is important that you list out the empty brackets inside of the "ArmorItems" tag, otherwise it will put the chestplate in the wrong spot.

I recommend [mcstacker](https://mcstacker.net/) for easily making custom items, mobs, and other things as it makes it easier to not have to remember a bunch of NBT tags.